# Angular 4/6/7 - How to get async variables?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await

I want to create a calculation like:

```
var a: number;
var b: number;
this.httpClient.get<int>(baseUrl+'varA/get/'+id).subscribe( res => this.a = res);
this.httpClient.get<int>(baseUrl+'varB/get/'+id).subscribe( res => this.b = res);

var c = a + b ;
```

How to subscribe asynchronously ? Usually I got var b after retriving var a. but I want to do async one (with async and await).... how to do that inside the subscribe() ?

I am using angular 7.

Comment: what exactly you want the process to do.

Comment: I want to get a and b async and then calculate both of them into c.

Comment: `let subscription = Observable.zip(obs1, obs2, ...).subscribe(...);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use fork join to make multiple requests.

```
public requestDataFromMultipleSources(baseUrl): Observable<any[]> {
    var a: number;
    var b: number;
    let response1 = this.httpClient.get<int>(baseUrl+'varA/get/'+id));
    let response2 = this.httpClient.get<int>(baseUrl+'varA/get/'+id)
    return Observable.forkJoin([response1, response2]);
  }

ngOnInit() {
        this.requestDataFromMultipleSources(this.baseUrl).subscribe(responseList => {
            let a = responseList[0];
            let b = responseList[1];
            var c = a + b 
     });
```

then subcribe to requestDataFromMultipleSources() function. this will parallelly make http requests and give the result. more details on this [link](https://medium.com/@swarnakishore/performing-multiple-http-requests-in-angular-4-5-with-forkjoin-74f3ac166d61)

Answer (score 1):

you should use rxjs conbinator observable like `combineLatest`.

here sample with dummy ajax request :

```
import { of, combineLatest } from 'rxjs'; 

const simulateQuery1$ = of(1); // Can be any observable
const simulateQuery2$ = of(3); // Can be any observable   
// CombineLatest will wait complete from both observable before next array of both value. work well for Ajax request who do 1 next then complete the observable.
combineLatest(simulateQuery1$, simulateQuery2$).subscribe(arrayVal => {
  console.log(arrayVal[0] + arrayVal[1]);
});
```

[live sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-bmggip)

Answer (score 0):

you can chain the promise using `RXJS`

```
var c;
getConditionalDataUsingPromise() {
    this.httpClient.get<int>(baseUrl+'varA/get/'+id).toPromise().then(data => {
      console.log('First Promise resolved.');
        this.httpClient.get<int>(baseUrl+'varB/get/'+id).toPromise().then(data => {
          this.c=data;
          console.log('Second Promise resolved.')
        });

    });
  }
```

Comment: Hi Manish, right pruposal to strictly answer to the original question. But in my opinion is not the right way to do it according to the Angular Standard. Please consider to never transform Observable to Promise inside RxJS Project.